# Auto-formatting in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to auto-format a spreadsheet with a specific conditions. On process completion, the sheet row should be auto-formatted (i.e alternate rows have same cell background color) and the header row, usually Row 1, with different color and font bold.

NOTE: THIS NEEDS TO BE DONE BY VBA CODE.

Also note, formatting needs to be done for "n" rows which have data, leaving the rest blank.

My pagelayout Code,

```
Public Function SetPageLayout(pworksheet)
'Set the page layout of the worksheet to be landscape and format to fit1 page

With Sheets(pworksheet).PageSetup
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .LeftMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)
    .RightMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)
    .TopMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)
    .BottomMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)
End With

End Function
```

Comment: We are not your code monkey... What did you try so far? Some source code?

Comment: Public Function SetPageLayout(pworksheet)
'Set the page layout of the worksheet to be landscape and format to fit1 page

With Sheets(pworksheet).PageSetup
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .LeftMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)
    .RightMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)
    .TopMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)
    .BottomMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)
End With

End Function

Comment: Edit your question for appropriate code highlighting.

Comment: Bash, i am not sure what bit of code to be added for generating alternate cell BG color and thats the intent of this post.

Comment: Have you considered Conditional Formatting in the Home tab of the ribbon?  Using the built-in features of Office tend to be faster than using VBA code.

Answer (score 3):

Record **Alt + O, A**. Which gives you

```
 Selection.AutoFormat Format:=xlRangeAutoFormatList1, Number:=True, Font:= _
    True, Alignment:=True, Border:=True, Pattern:=True, Width:=True
```

Record the steps in excel macro recorder. You have to rewrite it a bit because it uses a type of syntax that vbs doesn't.

This applies (I don't have a medium9) xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4 in vba.

```
Selection.AutoFormat Format:=xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4, Number:=True, _
    Font:=True, Alignment:=True, Border:=True, Pattern:=True, Width:=True
```

So first look up constants in vba's object browser. xlRangeAutoFormatAccounting4 = 17

Then look the function up in object browser and look at the bottom for the function definition,.

```
Function AutoFormat([Format As XlRangeAutoFormat = xlRangeAutoFormatClassic1], [Number], [Font], [Alignment], [Border], [Pattern], [Width])
```

So the vba becomes in vbs (and vbs works in vba) (and as you can see you can work out the correct way without needing to look the function up usually)

```
Selection.AutoFormat 17, True, True, True,True, True, True
```

So your code becomes

```
objXLWs.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Select.AutoFormat 17, True, True, True,True, True, True
```

You are using Excel and you can record it in Excel and have Excel write your code.

**Alt + T, M, R**

then **Home** key then **Up Arrow**. Stop recording.

Gee look what Excel wrote

```
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
```

or if you had of recorded Go To dialog

```
Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
```

or if you had of recorded Ctrl + Home

```
Range("A1").Select
```